# how do I update my variable using a function

Tags: javascript, function, global, local

I can't get the health variable updated..I get an update if i console.log it inside the function but it won't outside?

```
var health;
health = 9;

function scaringCat(event) {
    var catAngry = new Audio("sounds/cat_hiss.mp3");
    catAngry.play();

    health = health -1;
    return health;
}

buttons[1].addEventListener('click', scaringCat);
```

Comment: How are you actually testing this?  There's no reason why the variable wouldn't be updated.  But you're not actually examining the variable anywhere, so how do you know it isn't being updated?  (Or, to put it another way... It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/skrnzbyq/)

Comment: Your variable should be updated. If you refresh the page/restart the program you wont have the updated value of course. Moreover, if you are not assigning the return value somewhere, there is no reason to have it.

Comment: Where are you logging it outside of the function? Do you realize that the console line outside will not magically pick up the new number? You would  need to call or trigger something to get the new updated value.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this simple javascript code its updating health variable every time.Check console.

```
<body>

            <input type="button" value="Submit1" onclick="scaringCat()"></input>
            <input type="button" value="Submit2" onclick="scaringCat1()"></input>



<script type="text/javascript">
 var health;
    health = 9;

    function scaringCat() {
    health = health -1;

    console.log(health);
     alert("click on submit2 now!!!")
}

    function scaringCat1() {
    var v=health;
    console.log(v);

    }
    </script>

</body>
```